# MVVMLight v4.0.21.25721 SimpleIoc unregister and register not working

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services, mvvm-light

I'm trying to reset my IDataService (which is a wrapper for my interaction with my WCF Data Service) and is stored in the SimpleIoc.Default so that I can empty out the context and which entities it is tracking. I don't want to use Reset which removes everything from the containers.
I register my IDataService at startup: 
`SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();`

I'm trying this, but it isn't working as I expected and I'm getting this exception:

```
{System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.Register[TInterface,TClass](Boolean createInstanceImmediately)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.Register[TInterface,TClass]()
   at Bootstrap.ResetDataService()}

public static void ResetDataService()
{
    try
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<IDataService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this is a bug. I will fix it in the next release.

Please contact me if you need more info for your particular project, I can indicate you how to fix it in the source code and build your own version.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Thanks! I have a work around where I grab what I want from SimpleIoc, then call Reset(), then re-register the ones I saved using the factory method.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest release. See http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2012/06/03/mvvmlight-v4-for-windows-8-rp-is-available.aspx